# Finding number of digits in an integer

Tags: code-golf

Given an integer n as input write a program to output the numbers of digit in it.

**Input**

```
12346

456
```

**Output**

```
5

3
```

**Constraint**

```
n<=10^9
```

Comment: This seems overly trivial...

Comment: I agree with @DoorknobofSnow.  It should be trivial.  **But** many or most of the submitted answers are incorrect.  Any solution based on string.length alone (currently most, below) will output the wrong *number of digits* for any negative integer.  And most values of `n` *will* be negative, since "`n<=10^9`".  Just sayin'.  ;-)

Comment: Is the Input/Output example supposed to represent two separate inputs & outputs, or is the program supposed to be able to handle multiple integers at once? Also, are we required to support negative integers and if so what is the lower bound?

Comment: I have a feeling OP was looking for `(floor(log10(input))+1)` or something the likes (I think that's right anyway)

Comment: Should `00501` return `3` or `5`?

Comment: @Cruncher `log10(0)` and `log10(-1)` will fail for two different reasons.

Comment: @Dangling_pointer did you mean that |n|<=10⁹?

Comment: I'm voting to close as underspecified unless the challenge is improved.

Comment: @qwr : don't think it can be improved, it's 4 years old and OP has been inactive for over 1 year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## GolfScript, 1 character

```
,
```

`,` means length...

Edit: You seem to have changed your question... please don't do that, but I still have a solution:

## GolfScript, <s>12</s> 7 characters (for multiline)

```
n%{,n}/
```

Thanks @Howard for reminding me about `n` to push newline and using separate strings instead of one, to save 5 chars ;)

Solutions that work with negative numbers:

## GolfScript, 5 (for negative)

```
'-'-,
```

## GolfScript, 11 (for multiline and negative)

```
n%{'-'-,n}/
```

Comment: Only if input has no newline with it.

Comment: `n%{,}%n*` is much shorter ;-)

Comment: @Howard Thanks, forgot about `n` :)

Comment: Or even `n%{,n}/`.

Comment: @Howard Oh wow, thanks! Took a bit for me to figure out how that works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to stay away from the simple string length functions, but the BF solution basically does a count.

## Pure math/Mathematica - 22 chars (for mathematica)

```
floor(log10(abs(n)))+1
```

Thanks to @plg for the correction when n is a power of 10.
This invokes undefined behavior when n=0, but that case can be returned by a simple check.

## PHP implementation of the above math solution - 34 chars

```
($n==0)?1:floor(log(abs($n),10))+1;
```

## BrainF*ck - 54 characters

```
>>+[<+>++++++++++,----------]<-<++++++++[>++++++<-]>.
```

Comment: How about using [`log10()`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Log10.html) : `ceil(log10(abs(n))` EDIT: this won't work for powers of 10!

Comment: This took me longer than it should have, but here's a working pure math solution : `floor(log10(abs(n))) + 1`

Comment: @plg I'm just realizing that both of our solutions fail when x=0

Answer (score 4):

## Perl

```
s/\D//;$_=length
```

run as:

```
perl -ple 's/\D//;$_=length'
```

Comment: works correctly for negative, and "Perl style" numbers like 1_000_000

Comment: Nice use of `s///`, but I think you need a `g` at the end for numbers like 1_000_000_000? Also, how about `$_=s/\d//g`? :)

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the length of all input whether its an integer or not :( For eg. AAA returns 0 & a1a2 would return 2.

Comment: @draegtun This is codegolf; The question says nothing about invalid input, so you ignore it ("Given an integer n ...").

Comment: @daniero - Yes I maybe being pernickety however the example *input/output* provided does (currently!) show that an *empty* line returned as is.  Also note the constraint.

Comment: @draegtun There is no specification anywhere; The empty line could just as well be a way to separate two examples (in markdown two lines indented by four spaces, separated by an empty line, will show up as one code block). Other answers seem to behave similarly or disregard empty line as well. I read the constraint as "don't worry about numbers larger than 10^9".

Comment: @daniero - The question with the examples provided are a specification.  It's just that they're ambiguous hence open to varying interpretation!    re: constraint - very possible indeed, as is probably the intention to only use positive integers.

Comment: If you care about input validation, `perl -ple"$_=y/0-9//"` seems like the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

### python 2, 25

```
print len(`abs(input())`)
```

works for both positive and negative integers

Answer (score 3):

## Dc: 3 characters

```
?Zp
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ dc -e '?Zp' <<< '12346'
5

bash-4.2$ dc -e '?Zp' <<< '345'
3
```

Comment: I like how this (unintentionally?) works for negative numbers if you use something like `-123` as input.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (30 chars)

echo `$n<0?(strlen($n)-1):strlen($n)`

(without php opening tags `<?php` & `?>`)

### Explanation

Pretty simple, ints can be interpreted as strings, therefore `$n<0` has a minus-char that should be removed in the true-statement of the ternary operator. If its positive then we just count the length ;)

Comment: You need to count the tags, but you don't have to close them, and there is a shorter version (I think it was `<?`) so just prepend that to your code and you'll be good.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
i->(""+(i<0?-i:i)).length();
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntFunction<Integer> func = i -> ("" + (i < 0 ? -i : i)).length();

    System.out.println(func.apply(12345)); //5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### R, 25 bytes

```
cat(nchar(scan("stdin")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (with `-lp`) (11 bytes, counting `lp`)

```
$_=length
```

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge-98, 8 or 12 chars

**Single number** (actually counts input bytes ≥15 and prints count at EOF)

```
#.~f`+#@
```

**Multiline support** (same as above, but print count at byte <15 and reset counter)

```
#@~f`:2*j\.+
```

Comment: I thought `~$1+2j@.` makes more sense for single number.

Comment: I suppose so, but I wanted to support a trailing newline even for the single-number one, since it doesn't cost me anything.  As for the more straightforward `2j`, I usually forget about that, but you're right that it's prettier that way.

Answer (score 1):

## C - 59 characters

```
main(k){scanf("%i",&k);printf("%i\n",(int)log10(abs(k))+1);}
```

Comment: You can save a character by changing your variable declaration to be inside the function declaration: `main(k)`

Answer (score 1):

A DELPHI PROGRAM FOR CONSOLE

```
program P;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
var a: Integer;
begin
   readln(a);
   writeln(length(IntToStr(a)));
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby**

```
$*.first.size
```

or

```
ARGV.first.size
```

Comment: Welcome, shemerey.  Remember... code-golf...  keep it short.  Why not simply `$*[0].size`? (Aside from the negative integers issue.)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 22 bytes

```py
lambda a:len(`abs(a)`)
```

I actually built this myself, before seeing Wasi's answer! This is how I thought of it:

- I need: a `lambda`.
- `len`? `False`! What about `n<0`? Should the `-` be counted? `False`!
- How to eliminate the `-` in just a few bytes? `abs`!

*[Thinking ends]*

Comment: Seems this is one of only a few of the answers which *actually account for negative integers*. There go 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Go, 67 bytes

```
package main;import."fmt";func main(){s:="";Scan(&s);Print(len(s))}
```

Comment: len(strconv.Itoa(i))

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 20

```
alert((""+n).length)
```

Comment: “SyntaxError: return not in function” – Why you changed the `alert()`?

Comment: @manatwork Ok I will change it. I thought it was shorter with `return` but forgot that `return` has one more character than `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

## k [7 chars]

```
f:{#$x}
```

Example:

```
f 12346
5

f 456
3
```

Though only 2 characters (#$) are required to find the length of the input number.

```
#$123444
6
```

## Explanation

convert the input to string.

```
$123456
"123456"
```

count the number of characters:

```
#$123456
6
```

Q equivalent of this code:

```
f:{count string x}
f 123456
6
```

Answer (score 0):

#### R

The solution at 18 characters (identical in concept to the python solution of Wasi):

```
nchar(abs(scan()))
```

And the funnier one at 33 characters:

```
which(!abs(scan())%/%10^(1:9))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb), 3

Assuming value is already stored:

```
l?_
```

To make user input:

```
`_l?_
```

Newline support with interactive input:

```
[`_~l?_]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl

#### 15 chars - no input or constraint checks

```
$_=()=$_=~/\d/g
```

#### 48 chars - checks input & constraint

```
$_=/^-?(\d+)$/?($1<=10**9?length($1)."\n":$_):$_
```

NB. If the input (`$_`) is an integer (positive or negative) and comes under the constraint then it amends `$_` to the number of digits.  Otherwise it just leaves the input as is.

Usage example:

```
perl -ple '... insert above code...'
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell (25)

```
($n-replace"-",'').length
```

where $n is a number

Comment: Incorrect for negative numbers

Comment: @AdamSpeight Arguably, the challenge is unclear (and the OP has yet to edit it in response to this and other points) with regards to negative numbers. However, adding negative number support would bring it to 39: `$x="$n".length;if($n-ge0){$x}else{$x-1}`

Comment: I have modified my answer, i think it should work for negative numbers.  The question is very unclear, it is unbounded on negative side.

Comment: @microbian Kill two more characters - the spaces are unnecessary.

Comment: Scratch another character - substitute `'-'` instead of `"\D"`.

Comment: @Iszi, thanks.  Should have thought about the '-' already.

Answer (score 0):

### C, <strike>63</strike> <strike>59</strike> 57 characters

<strike>It's slightly longer than the other C solution,</strike> but it works on arbitrarily large numbers (numbers with `2^32 - 1` digits rather than numbers up to `2^32 - 1`).

EDIT: It's now shorter than the other C solution!

```
c;main(n){n-10?main(getchar(),c+=n>47):printf("%d\n",c);}
```

Note: if you call the program with exactly 9 arguments, it will fail.  But why would you do that??

Answer (score 0):

## bash - 19 characters

Assuming input via standard input:

```
grep -o [0-9]|wc -l
```

Multi-line version - 48 characters:

```
while read L;do echo $L|grep -o [0-9]|wc -l;done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### APL - 4 characters

```
ρ'n'
```

The first symbol, rho, checks the number of cells in an array, where one character of a string is equal to one cell.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 26 bytes

```
puts [string length $argv]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6uKQoMy9dISc1L70kQ0ElsSi9LPb///@GRsYmZgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þg
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8L70//91DY2MAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/X9u6//D@9L/xx7a/T/a0MjYxExHwcQUSOgCOToKBkCGpWUsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ     # Take the digits of the input
 g    # And output the length
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 2 bytes

```
ìl
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=7Gw=&input=LTEyMzQ1)

`ì` converts to a digit array and `l` gets the length.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
âL
```

Gets the length of the Absolute Value of the input. Trivial.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///wIp/////rGpoaGAEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 5 bytes

```
!s*dl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fsVgrJef///@6RpamFmamAA)

As with all the others, `abs` then `len`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thing](https://gitlab.com/gnu-nobody/Thinglang), 12 bytes

```
idh\-=[tLe]L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nIzEv//z8zJSNG1za6xCc11uf///@6pgA)

### How?

Gets input from command line arguments. If the first character of input is "-", push the length of the all but first items of the string and immediately end the program. Else, push the length of the string. Then implicitly print.

Does not work with multiline.

```
i push input
d duplicate
h first character of
\- push the character "-"
= if top two values are equal, push 1, if not, 0
    [ if top value is truthy (not [] or 0), go into the block. if not,  go past the end of the block. 
    t push the all but first items of the stack's top value (literally s[1:] in python)
    L length
    e end the program
    ] end loop
L length
```